# Ansible accessing Nested Variables

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In foo.yml, the `dev.foo` variable contains a value of bar.

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    dev:
      foo: bar
```

I set the `env` variable to contain a value of `dev` on the command line.

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml --extra-vars "env=dev"
```

If I attempt to debug `env.foo` . . .

```
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ env.foo }}"
```

The following is returned.

```
TASK [debug]
fatal: [server1.example.com]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable.
            The error was: 'str object' has no attribute 'foo'"
}
```

I am not sure how to resolve `env` to `dev` in jinja2 and then access nested variable `dev.foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirect addressing is not available in [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-simple-variables). You can use `vars` lookup instead. See `ansible-doc -t lookup vars` e.g.

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('vars', env).foo }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: bar
```

Comment: That's awesome Vladimir. I think that lookup is exactly what I needed here. Thanks a bunch!